# getting a OUTOFRANGE error with vector in c++ when using insert method

Tags: c++, error-handling, indexoutofrangeexception

I am getting a OUTOFRANGE error with vector in c++ when using insert method. I don't know why this is happening but I was able to narrow down the problem to one line through debugging. Here is the full code.

```
//

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class suffixArray{


public: suffixArray(std:: string concatenated ){


    vector<int> attempt1;

    const int size = (int)concatenated.length();
    int rank[7] = {};

    char *suffixPointers[concatenated.length()];
    int value[concatenated.length()];

    for(int i =0; i <= size-1; i++){
        suffixPointers[i] = &concatenated[i];
        value[i] = (int)concatenated[i];
    }
    std::cout << "[";
    for(int i = 0; i<= size-1; i++){

        std::cout  <<value[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "]"<< std:: endl;




    for(int i = 0; i<=size -1; i++){
        if(i == 0){
            rank[i] = i;
            attempt1.push_back(i);
        }
        else if(value[i] > value[i-1]){
            rank[i] = i;
            attempt1.push_back(i);
        }else{
            int current =i;
            int savedValue = value[i];
            int prevSavedRank;
            int indexcounter = i;
            while(savedValue <= value[attempt1.at(indexcounter-1)] && indexcounter - 1 >= 0  ){
                indexcounter--;

            }
            cout << indexcounter << endl;
            attempt1.insert(attempt1.begin() + indexcounter ,i);
//            while(savedValue <= value[rank[current-1]] && current-1 >= 0){
//                prevSavedRank= rank[current-1];
//                rank[current-1] = i;
//                rank[current] = prevSavedRank;
//                current--;
//            }
        }
    }

    int now;
    for(int i = 0; i<= 3; i++){
        now = attempt1[i];
        std::cout <<  now << " ";
    }
}
};





void read_file(string filename, string& contents, int& num_lines){
    ifstream f;
    f.open(filename.c_str());
    string line;

    contents = "";
    num_lines = 0;
    while(getline(f, line)){
        contents.append(line.substr(0, line.length()));
        num_lines++;
    }

    f.close();
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    std:: string test = "BANANA$";
    suffixArray testString (test);

    string fn;
    string contents;
    int num_lines;

    cout << "File 1:" << endl;
    cin>> fn;
    read_file(fn, contents, num_lines);

    cout << "Read: " << fn << "\n";
    cout << "  * " << num_lines << " lines\n";
    cout << "  * " << contents.length() << " characters (excluding newlines)\n";
    //cout <<"   * " << contents << endl;

   // char * contents_cstring = (char*)contents.c_str();
    //for(int i =0; i< contents.length(); i++){
     //   assert(contents_cstring[i] == *(contents_cstring + 1));
       // assert(contents_cstring[i] == contents.at(i));
    //}
    //assert(contents_cstring[contents.length()] == '\0');
    return 0;
}
```

I have narrowed down the problem to be the problem to be from this line, but can not figure out why it is occurring, or how to fix it.

attempt1.insert(attempt1.begin() + indexcounter ,i);

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575669/10957435) help at all?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, I actually meant out of range exception, I just edited my question. Thank you anyways though!

Comment: and what is `indexcounter` and `attemp1.size()` at that time?

Comment: `int value[concatenated.length()];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by compile-time constant expressions, not a runtime value.  You are using `std::vector`, so why did you not use it here? `std::vector<int> value(concatenated.length())`.

Comment: Ran your code through a compiler. Lot of warnings you may want to address. They could be important.

Comment: Rather than prefer `i < size` to `i <= size-1`. The compiler probably will clean it all up for you, but people will look at you funny.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first time the program reaches

```
int indexcounter = i;
while(savedValue <= value[attempt1.at(indexcounter-1)] && indexcounter - 1 >= 0){
    indexcounter--;

}
```

`i` will be 1. `indexcounter-1` will be 0. If the loop is entered,

```
int indexcounter = 1;
while(savedValue <= value[attempt1.at(0)] && 0 >= 0  ){
    1--;

}
```

OK, so what happens the next time?

```
while(savedValue <= value[attempt1.at(-1)] && -1 >= 0  ){
    0--;

}
```

`value[attempt1.at(-1)]` happens before -1 >= 0, s the trap to prevent -1 fails. Reverse the order of the tests.

```
while(indexcounter - 1 >= 0 && savedValue <= value[attempt1.at(indexcounter-1)])
```

Could be more bugs, but after that the program hangs and asks for a file that I don't have.