# Runtime error in - Maximum difference between node and its ancestor in Binary Tree

Tags: c++, runtime-error, binary-tree

Question:
Given a Binary Tree, you need to find the **maximum value** which you can get **by subtracting** the **value of** node **B from** the value of node **A**, where A and B are two nodes of the binary tree and **A is an ancestor of B**. Complete the function: maxDiff(Node*).
Sample input : 8 3 10 1 6 N 14 N N 4 7 13 N //(level order)
Sample output: 7                            //(8-1)
Constraints :
1 <= Number of edges <= 10^4
0 <= Data of a node <= 10^5

Question link:
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/maximum-difference-between-node-and-its-ancestor/1#

What I'm trying to do:
I created a map<Node*, vector> to store all ancestors of each node. Then I'm traversing the tree and continuously updating the ancestor map. Finally, I iterate through the map and find the result.

My code:

```
void traverse(Node* root, unordered_map<Node*,vector<int>> &m)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return;
    
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    if(root->left != NULL)
    {
        vector<int> curr; // to store all ancestors of root->left
        curr.push_back(root->data);//add immediate parent of root->left  
        if(m.find(root) != m.end())   
        {
            vector<int> temp = m[root];//store all ancestors of root
            for(int i=0; i<temp.size(); i++)
            {
                curr.push_back(temp[i]);//all ancestors of root are also
                                        //...ancestors of root->left
            }
        }
        m[root->left] = curr;    //update map
        traverse(root->left,m);  //Continue for root->left
        
    }
    
    if(root->right != NULL)
    {
        vector<int> curr1;// to store all ancestors of root->right
        curr1.push_back(root->data);
                         //add immediate parent of root->right
        
        if(m.find(root) != m.end())
        {
            vector<int> temp1 = m[root]; //store all ancestors of root
            for(int i=0; i<temp1.size(); i++)
            {
                curr1.push_back(temp1[i]);
                //all ancestors of root are also ancestor of root->right
            }
        }
        m[root->right] = curr1;  //update map
        traverse(root->right,m); //continue for root->right
    }
    
}


int maxDiff(Node* root)
{
    unordered_map<Node*, vector<int>> m;
    if(root==NULL || (root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL))
        return 0;
    vector<int> v;
    m[root] = v;      //root has no ancestors, so a 0 sized vector
    traverse(root,m);
    
    //Now m contains all nodes as keys and value as vector<int>, which
    //..is vector of all ancestors (ancestors' data) 
    int resmax = INT_MIN;
    int a,b;
    vector<int> t;
    
    for(auto itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); itr++)
    {
        b = itr->first->data;  //child
        t = itr->second;       //all ancestor
        
        for(int i=0;  i<t.size(); i++)
        {
            a = t[i];   //current ancestor
            if(resmax < a-b)
                resmax = a-b;
        }
    }
    return resmax;
}
```

I know there can be better solutions in O(n) and other approaches, but I'm a beginner and I want to know, **why is my program giving runtime(sigabrt) error** (although the same program is working fine on leetcode- with somewhat relaxed constraints).
I'm not looking for a new solution, Just the reason why this is giving run-error or some changes in my code itself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you checking for `distance` between nodes or the `difference` between node `contents`?

Comment: I'm checking for difference between node contents (a-b, where a is data of ancestor and b is data of child), as asked in the question

Comment: you can also use the provided link for better understanding @ThomasMatthews

Comment: Most likely the reason behind it, is that in case of big edge numbers, you create a lot of elements in your map with a really big vectors. So if, for example, number of edges is 10^4 amount of `int`s in all your `vector`s could be about 5*10^7, which could be to much to handle for a system. It also explains why it worked on leetcode with an easier constraints and it is one of common reasons for **runtime(sigabrt)**

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. But, we know that a vector can have a maximum size of like 4*10^17. And in your case (for a fully skewed tree), the maximum no of elements any vector would have to hold is 10^4. Total no of operation is as you pointed out is 5*10^7, and also we know that generally, the system can do 10^8 operations, which I now think is the problem is here (too many operations). But shouldn't it give TLE instead of sigabrt error? @BomberCubit

Comment: There is a thing, that there more restrictions for a size then just restriction for a maximum size of a `vector`. For example, you could easily check that in order to contain vector with a size of 4*10^17 you need thousands gigabytes of RAM, which is definitely too much. So there is a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415362/sigabrt-error-codechef) and the reason for the same error was that there is array with 10^8 `int` elements. So if you have map with 10^4 elements with about 10^4 sized vectors, it is a similar problem.@Shinigami_Zabuza

Comment: There wouldn't be TLE because in reality 10^8 operations is not so much

Answer (score 1):

It has a simple trick.
For some node 'n', let it has k children in its subtree with numbers = {a1, a2, ..., ak}

The catch here is that you only need the minimum of all these numbers as your answer of that particular node is max(n->data - ai->data) for 1<=i<=k.
so, for each node, recursively calculate the smallest number in its subtree and update the answer.